# List containing which servers connects to specific queue

Tags: list, ip, queue, rabbitmq, rmq

Im new to rabbit MQ and I already know how to list queues and work with the basic functions, but I don't know if there is a way to list the specific servers/ip's that connect to a specific queue, e.g.

rabbitmqctl [Search_Specific_ip] [From_queue_name]

thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could query for consumers using the [command line](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html#list_consumers) or the [web API](http://d0vbbmessaging.victor-buck.com:15672/api/).

The web API will return an array of this type:

```
{
  "channel_details": {
    "name": "192.168.0.1:42424 -> 192.168.0.2:5672 (1)",
    "number": 1,
    "user": "rabbituser",
    "connection_name": "192.168.0.1:42424 -> 192.168.0.2:5672",
    "peer_port": 42424,
    "peer_host": "192.168.0.1"
  },
  "queue": {
    "name": "queueName",
    "vhost": "vhost"
  },
  "consumer_tag": "amq.ctag-HJ_eUK1IcA3TMIMQGOVtcg",
  "exclusive": false,
  "ack_required": true,
  "prefetch_count": 1,
  "arguments": {}
}
```